# Converting HTML Entities in UTF-8 to SHIFT_JIS

Tags: php, character-encoding, html-entities

I am working with a website that needs to target old, Japanese mobile phones, that are not Unicode enabled.  The problem is, the text for the site is saved in the database as HTML entities (ie, &#1234;).  This database absolutely cannot be changed, as it is used for several hundred websites.

What I need to do is convert these entities to actual characters, and then convert the string encoding before sending it out, as the phones render the entities without converting them first.

I've tried both `mb_convert_encoding` and `iconv`, but all they are doing is converting the encoding of the entities, but not creating the text.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

I have also tried `html_entity_decode`.  It is producing the same results - an unconverted string.

Here is the sample data I am working with.

The desired result: シェラトン・ヌーサリゾート＆スパ

The HTML Codes: `&#12471;&#12455;&#12521;&#12488;&#12531;&#12539;&#12492;&#12540;&#12469;&#12522;&#12478;&#12540;&#12488;&#65286;&#12473;&#12497;`

The output of `html_entity_decode([the string above],ENT_COMPAT,'SHIFT_JIS');` is identical to the input string.

Comment: does `html_entity_decode()` not work on them?

Comment: I've updated the question.  `html_entity_decode` does not convert correctly.

Comment: @MattBelanger: What *is* the encoding of the original string?

Comment: @hakre The original string is in UTF-8, which is why the html_entity_decode did not work originally.  A combination of fixing that and then converting with iconv seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: @MattBelanger: Okay, exactly what I had assumed, see my answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take care you're creating the right codepoints out of the entities. If the original encoding is UTF-8 for example:

```
$originalEncoding = 'UTF-8'; // that's only assumed, you have not shared the info so far
$targetEncoding = 'SHIFT_JIS';
$string = '... whatever you have ... ';
// superfluous, but to get the picture:
$string = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-8', $originalEncoding);
$string = html_entity_decode($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
$stringTarget = mb_convert_encoding($string, $targetEncoding, 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this function on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php#refsect1-function.html-entity-decode-examples), it works for me with your example:

```
function unhtmlentities($string) {
    // replace numeric entities
    $string = preg_replace('~&#x([0-9a-f]+);~ei', 'chr(hexdec("\\1"))', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('~&#([0-9]+);~e', 'chr("\\1")', $string);
    // replace literal entities
    $trans_tbl = get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES);
    $trans_tbl = array_flip($trans_tbl);
    return strtr($string, $trans_tbl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need [`html_entity_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php).

**Edit:** Based on your edit:

```
$output = preg_replace_callback("/(&#[0-9]+;)/", create_function('$m', 'return mb_convert_encoding($m[1], "UTF-8", "HTML-ENTITIES"); '), $original_string);
```

Note that this is just your first step, to convert your entities to the actual characters.

Answer (score 0):

just to participate as I encountered some kind of encoding bug while coding, I would suggest this snippet :

```
 $string_to_encode=" your string ";
 if(mb_detect_encoding($string_to_encode)!==FALSE){
      $converted_string=mb_convert_encoding($string_to_encode,'UTF-8');
 }
```

Maybe not the best for a large amount of data, but still works.